# Can I use an rsync log file from a dry run as an input to a real run?

Tags: backup, rsync, backup-strategies

I like rsync.  I can see what files will be deleted first.  But what happens if during the backup, a sector of the source disk fails?  Files could be deleted from the destination that should not be.  However, if I check the log file for all deletion files first, then use the log file as instructions to rsync, then a source disk failure during backup should result in a lower probability of data loss.

I've read the man page and have to conclude that the answer is no.  If not rsync, then what?

Answer (score 0):

You can mitigate source disk failure risk using

```
 --delete-after          receiver deletes after transfer, not during
```

That will not delete files if a IO error is produced during copy.

But for ensuring integrity of your backup, I think the right way is using:

```
 --only-write-batch=FILE like --write-batch but w/o updating destination
```

That will write diffs into a file. Once batch is created, you move it to destination machine, and apply diffs with:

```
 --read-batch=FILE       read a batched update from FILE
```